# Equivalent resistance of resistors

Tags: resistors, resistance, parallel, series

Can somebody help me solve this. I need to find the equivalent resistance of these resistors. I really don't know where the trick here is. If somebody could help me I would really appreciate it
[image]

Comment: If there is a 'trick' it is to redraw the circuits so that you can see the actual arrangement. With practice, you can do it in your head.

Comment: Was about to say that @SpehroPefhany

Comment: Give each node a name and then try to redraw and simplify...

Comment: And check your third one. Do you see anything tricky about the jumper?

Answer (score 2):

You need to redraw the circuits, I did the first one. Then you can use regular circuit theory to combine resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSlVMc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First circuit: all resistors in parallel. (every is connected to A by one side and to B by other side)

Second circuit: first is in series with following 3 that are also in parallel. (almost same as first, only added one resistor before parallel)

Third: shorted (Rek=0) (A to B over diagonal short connect)

Comment: We prefer to rather give hints instead of outright answers to questions which are clearly homework.

Comment: I am sorry, I edited my answer.